# How to make two lists reference each other?

Tags: python, list, reference

I currently have something like this:

```
x = [['Bob', 'Mary', 'Mary', 'John'], [10, 20, 22, 19]]
```

How do I link Bob to 10, Mary to both 20 and 22, and John to 19? I'm trying to add their totals together so that it would result in:

```
Bob: 10
Mary: 42
John: 19
```

Comment: Please update your question with the code you have tried.

Comment: They are already linked by their common indices in the their respective sublists.

Comment: zip lists & use a collections.Counter

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the
[intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).  
Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing tutorials and documentation.
You need to define "link"; if you simply want correspondence of *any* sort, then you need to work through tutorials on basic Python data structures and access methods.  `zip` or `dict` may be what you want, but you haven't explained your use case well enough.

Comment: the code is valid python if identifiers are string variables. But, yeah, OP probably forgot the quotes

Answer (score 1):

You can use `defaultdict` to accumulate the values for each name:

```
from collections import defaultdict

x = [["Bob", "Mary", "Mary", "John"], [10, 20, 22, 19]]

totals = defaultdict(int)
for name, value in zip(x[0], x[1]):
    totals[name] += value

print(totals)  
# defaultdict(<type 'int'>, {'Bob': 10, 'John': 19, 'Mary': 42})

print(f'Bob: {totals["Bob"]} Mary: {totals["Mary"]} John: {totals["John"]}') 
# Bob: 10 Mary: 42 John: 19

print(" ".join([f"{name}: {value}" for name, value in totals.items()])) # print dynamically all pairs
# Bob: 10 Mary: 42 John: 19
```

Answer (score 0):

zip the sublists and use a loop to count/gather elements by key:

```
import collections

x = [["Bob", "Mary", "Mary", "John"], [10, 20, 22, 19]]

result = collections.Counter()
for k,v in zip(*x):
    result[k] += v

print(result)
```

prints:

```
Counter({'Mary': 42, 'John': 19, 'Bob': 10})
```